# Required input after non required input

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, forms

I got trouble coding on giving required attribute on upload tab but on the select option won't input on database when I choose "AKTIF"

This is my code

```
 <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
  <select class="form-control form-control-lg" name="STATUS" id="STATUS">
    <label>STATUS</label>
     <option value="Aktif">AKTIF</option>
        <option value="Tidak Aktif">TIDAK AKTIF</option>
  </select>
  <div class="form-group" id='upload' style="display:none;">
    <label>UPLOAD FOTO DOKUMEN</label>
    <input type="file" name="uploaddiniyah" class="form-control">
        
    </textarea>
  </div>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" name="ubah">Konfirmasi</button>
 </form>

 <script> 
let status = document.getElementById('STATUS');
let upload = document.getElementById('upload');
status.onchange = function()
{
  if(this.value === "Tidak Aktif"){
    upload.style.display = 'block';
  }else{
    upload.style.display = 'none';
  }
}
</script>
<?php

?>
 <?php 
  if (isset($_POST['ubah'])) {
    if(empty($_POST['uploaddiniyah'])){
    $err="mohon pilih file";
  }else{
    $uploaddiniyah = true;
    $namafoto = $_FILES ['uploaddiniyah']['name'];
    $lokasifoto = $_FILES ['uploaddiniyah']['tmp_name'];
    move_uploaded_file($lokasifoto, "../fotodokumen/".$namafoto);
    //jk foto dirubah
    $koneksi->query("UPDATE diniyah SET status='$_POST[STATUS]' WHERE ID='$_GET[id]'");
    $update_gambar=mysqli_query($koneksi,"UPDATE diniyah SET uploaddiniyah='$namafoto' WHERE ID='$_GET[id]'");

    echo "<script>alert(Status pegawai telah diubah);</script>";
  }
}
  ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your comment do like below:

```
let status = document.getElementById('STATUS');
let upload = document.getElementById('upload');
status.onchange = function()
{
  if(this.value === "Tidak Aktif"){
    upload.style.display = 'block';
     document.getElementById('file').required = true;
  }else{
    upload.style.display = 'none';
     document.getElementById('file').required = false;
  }
}
```

***Working snippet:***

```js
let status = document.getElementById('STATUS');
let upload = document.getElementById('upload');
status.onchange = function()
{
  if(this.value === "Tidak Aktif"){
    upload.style.display = 'block';
     document.getElementById('file').required = true;
  }else{
    upload.style.display = 'none';
     document.getElementById('file').required = false;
  }
}
```

```html
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
  <select class="form-control form-control-lg" name="STATUS" id="STATUS">
    <label>STATUS</label>
     <option value="Aktif">AKTIF</option>
        <option value="Tidak Aktif">TIDAK AKTIF</option>
  </select>
  <div class="form-group" id='upload' style="display:none;">
    <label>UPLOAD FOTO DOKUMEN</label>
    <input type="file" id="file" name="uploaddiniyah" class="form-control">
        
    </textarea>
  </div>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" name="ubah" id="Konfirmasi">Konfirmasi</button>
 </form>
```

Note:- You have to add `id="file"` on your file input field. Like below:

```
<input type="file" id="file" name="uploaddiniyah" class="form-control">
```

***Apart from it*** I am agreed with what @Dharman said in comment(Under question).

Comment: it needs to have "required" attribute on upload input, but when i add "required" on my upload input like   <input type="file" name="uploaddiniyah" class="form-control" required> . but when i add required and the option selected to "AKTIF" it cant be inputted on the database